# rake aborted! uninitialized constant Gem::UserInteraction on OSX when using Octopress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, rake, octopress

I use Octopress to write a blog, today when I normally used commmand rake generate there were error popped out, I Googled and it said may be the gem version issue, so I tried to update but still had error. So anyone could give me an advice? 
Thanks in advance.

Here's the terminal command:

stevenlordiam:octopress stevenlordiam$ rake generate

rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Gem::UserInteraction

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

stevenlordiam:octopress stevenlordiam$ sudo gem update --system

Password:

/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/config_file.rb:39: uninitialized constant Gem::UserInteraction (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1430:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in`build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in`find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1031:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in`each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in`find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:8
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/command.rb:9
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:8
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /usr/bin/gem:9

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself. Octopress needs Ruby 1.9.3 or greater, but I used Ruby 1.8. Simply install Ruby 1.9.3 and use command `rbenv global 1.9.3-p0`will solve this problem.